# Observer on LiveData still active after removeObservers

Tags: java, android, android-livedata, observers

I select Information from DB using LiveData, passing it to my Activity (via DAO, Repository & Viewmodel) dependent from a timespan of Dates. When I change the timespan, I want to remove the old Observers on the LiveData and create new Observer for the new Timespan.

```java
private void addStepsObserver(Date[] timeSpan) {
    homeViewModel.getSteps(timeSpan[0], timeSpan[1]).observe(this, new Observer<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(Integer integer) {
            if (integer == null) {
                return;
            }
            Log.i(StepRepository.TAG, "onChanged for getSteps().observe called " + integer);
            updateStepCounter(integer);
        }
    });
}

private void removeObservers() {
    Date[] timeSpan = homeViewModel.getCurrentTimespan();
    homeViewModel.getSteps(timeSpan[0], timeSpan[1]).removeObservers(this);
    Log.i(TAG, "remove Observers " + timeSpan[0] + " " + timeSpan[1]);
}
```

However, after I call `removeObservers()` and then `addStepsObservers(timespan)` with timespan being another timestamp than before, the method `updateStepCounter()` is called by both observers, although the old one isn't active anymore (I checked that using `.hasObservers()` and `.hasActiveObservers()`)

Any advices?

Comment: if `homeViewModel.getCurrentTimespan()` is only returning data, then `removeObservers` is not calling any method to remove the observers

Comment: I edited the code, failed something when copying and pasting it to stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`homeViewModel.getSteps()` - returns a new `LiveData` for each call? So, it means that you remove an observer from another newly created `LiveData`. You have to keep a reference to `LiveData` object created in `addStepsObserver` step and in `removeObservers` step you should remove observers from it.